# Trying to rerun skjerm() if input<1 or >10. But it doesnt' do anything when i write mentioned values. Using 3.2

Tags: python, input

```
def skjerm():

    try:

        tall=int(input("Skriv inn et tall: "))
        if 10<tall<1:

            skjerm()
        else:
            main(tall)

    except ValueError:
        print ("Error")
        skjerm()
```

Trying to rerun skjerm() if input<1 or >10. But it doesnt' do anything when i write mentioned values. Using 3.2

Comment: Doesnt work. It just does nothing. No errors, nothing. Just a new line ">>>".

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong then you should use `if 10<tall or tall<1:` instead of `if 10<tall<1`, because the latter will always be `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if not (1 <= tall <= 10): # or < if that's really what you want
    pass # do whatever
```

Or, you could do:

```
if tall not in range(1, 11):
    pass # do something
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, guys. Can't believe I missed that :)

Answer (score 0):

Chained comparisons are combined with `and`, so

```
10 < tall < 1
```

is the same as

```
(10 < tall) and (tall < 1)
```

which is always false.

Try `(10 < tall) or (tall < 1)` instead.